# Constrained minimization: characterizing derivatives of optimum with respect to parameters

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, chain-rule, constraints

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$ defined on $[0,1]^2$ that is equal to the value of the following constrained minimization problem:

$$f(x,y) = min_{a\in [0,1-x),\ b\in[0,x)}\ \left\{ h(x,a) + g(x,b) \right\}\ \text{subject to } a+b=y$$

Here is some relevant information about $h$ and $g$. First, $h(x,0)=g(x,0)$ for all $x$. Second, $\lim_{a\rightarrow 1-x} h(x,a)=\infty$ and $\lim_{b\rightarrow x}g(x,b)=\infty$ (this is why I write the feasible sets as partially open intervals).

I am interested in an analytical characterization of the partial derivatives $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $h$ and $g$. My envelope theorem is super rusty, and the simplicity of both the objective and the constraint make me think there is a relatively easy solution here that I am missing.

Note this is not homework (I am not a student, but rather an old professor who has come to rely perhaps too heavily on numerical methods for his own good).

Here is my logic so far:

(i) The simplest case is if $x=0$, where $b=0$ and $a=y$ by construction. Obviously in this case $f(0,y)$ = $h(0,y)$ for all $y$. Then $f_x(0,y) = h_x(0,y)$ and $f_y(0,y) = h_a(0,y)$.

(ii) If $x>0$ but we have a corner solution (either $a=0$ or $b=0$), the answer is still pretty simple. If $a=0$ then $f_x(x,y)=g_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)=g_b(x,y)$. If $b=0$ then $f_x(x,y) = h_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y) = h_a(x,y)$ as in (i).

(iii) For interior solutions, the first-order conditions imply $h_a(x,a^*(x,y))=g_b(x,b^*(x,y))$, where $a^*(x,y)$ and $b^*(x,y)$ are the argmins. I am thinking $f_y(x,y)=h_a(x,a^*(x,y))=g_b(x,b^*(x,y))$ in this case. At the margin, allocating a small increase in y to a or b should have the same effect on the objective.

[iv] The only thing I am left with is: what is $f_x(x,y)$ for interior solutions?

Comment: You might be able to use the infimal convolution and convex conjugate for that. It looks like your problems structure fits the model $h_1\square h_2(\mathbf{x}) = min_{\mathbf{u}\in U}\{h1_u)+h_2(\mathbf{x-u})\}$. Then the conjugate of the convolution $(h_1\square h_2)^* = h_1^*+h_2^*$. Given the knowledge you already have this might be enough to derive the last missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this, but it would be extremely useful to get some feedback to verify this solution.

We can get rid of the constraint $a+b=y$ and write the problem as
$$f(x,y)=\min_{a\in(y-x,y]\cap[0,x)}\ \{h(x,a)+g(x,y-a)\}$$
Restricting attention to interior solutions where $0<a<y$, the first-order condition is $$h_a(x,a^*(x,y))=g_b(x,y-a^*(x,y))$$

We can write $f_x$ as
$$f_x(x,y)=h_x(x,a^*(x,y))+h_a(x,a^*(x,y))a^*_x(x,y)+g_x(x,y-a^*(x,y))-g_b(x,y-a^*(x,y))a^*_x(x,y)$$
Using the FOC, this simplifies to
$$f_x(x,y)=h_x(x,a^*(x,y))+g_x(x,y-a^*(x,y))$$
This is a bit comforting, as it appears to be the standard envelope condition result.

We can write $f_y$ as
$$f_y(x,y)=h_a(x,a^*(x,y))a^*_y(x,y)+g_b(x,y-a^*(x,y))\left[1-a^*_y(x,y)\right]$$
Using the FOC again, we get
$$f_y(x,y)=g_b(x,y-a^*(x,y))=h_a(x,a^*(x,y))$$
This verifies the answer I proposed in item (iii) of my question.

For corner solutions, I believe the answers proposed in (i) and (ii) of my question are correct.